# Does Android WebView Support for requestPointerLock()?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, pointerlock

I am trying to use `requestPointerLock` from Javascript on Android.  I got some errors when trying the most basic things, so I tried out some examples like [this](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/pointer-lock/) or [this](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Scorched_Earth_1991) don't work.  At the same time, I read that the API should be supported in Android Chrome.  Does anyone have a working example of this?

The specific error I get is similar to what I see in the 2nd example when running it: `WrongDocumentError: The root document of this element is not valid for pointer lock.`
I want to debug that issue, but I want to see any example working first.